# aspnet_users table is empty but c# code indicates that users exist

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm creating a small asp.net webforms application using membership, windows authorization, and sqlprovider.  aspnet tables were created using aspnet_regsql.exe tool in sqlexpress db (same db as non-membership content).  In page_load of default.aspx.cs I create a user:
var x = System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(@"larry-gateway\larry", "Gilmgilm1");
I test for its presence using:
 var me_the_User = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(@"larry-gateway\larry");
and I get an object.
I try to add it again and it fails - duplicate.
But I look in aspnet_users and it's empty!
So I must be creating it in a different db, not .\sqlexpress; I check connection strings and there are no others than the one I wanted.
I search for similar problem and they seem to indicate that my problem is that I am accessing different db.  I'm trying to include my web.config but submission checker seems to be unhappy with my use of 3 spaces for tabs as well as other things. 
Here is web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear/>
        <!--  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-FSISIssues7-20150731095953;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-FSISIssues7-20150731095953.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
        <add name="FSIS-IssuesConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LARRY-GATEWAY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FSIS-Issues;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
         <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=LARRY-GATEWAY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FSIS-Issues;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
         <add name="SqlRoleManager" connectionString="Data Source=LARRY-GATEWAY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FSIS-Issues;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="SqlProvider" 
            enabled="true"
            cacheRolesInCookie="true"
            cookieName=".ASPROLES"
            cookieTimeout="30"
            cookiePath="/"
            cookieRequireSSL="false"
            cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
            cookieProtection="All" >
            <providers>
                <add
                name="SqlProvider"
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
                connectionStringName="FSIS-IssuesConnection"
                applicationName="FSISIssues" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            </namespaces>
        <controls>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
        </controls></pages>
        <authentication mode="Windows">

            <!-- <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />  -->
        </authentication>
        <profile defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
            <providers>
                <clear/>

                <add name="SqlRoleManager"

                    type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"

                    connectionStringName="FSIS-IssuesConnection"

                    applicationName="FSISIssues" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
            <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
                  <providers>
                        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="FSIS-IssuesConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="FSISIssues" />
                  </providers>
            </membership>
            <!--<roleManager  enabled="true" defaultProvider="SQLRoleProvider">


              <providers>
                    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="FSIS-IssuesConnection" applicationName="FSISIssues" />
              </providers>  
        </roleManager>-->
        <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
        -->
        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
                <providers>
                    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="FSIS-IssuesConnection" />
                </providers>
        </sessionState>
  </system.web>
      <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                  <dependentAssembly>
                        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
                        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
                  </dependentAssembly>
                  <dependentAssembly>
                        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
                        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
                  </dependentAssembly>
                  <dependentAssembly>
                        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
                        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
                  </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
            <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
                  <parameters>
                        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
                  </parameters>
            </defaultConnectionFactory>
            <providers>
                <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            </providers>
      </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Ethan: thank you. I ran it but there is no db in app_data (not in solution explorer nor in files (Windows Explorer).  No entry was added to my aspnet_users table either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because,

> The membership database is also stored as an .mdf file in the App_Data
>   folder. You will be able to view this database once the first user has
>   signed in to this web application.

Comment: I am using windows authentication (intranet application) and remember seeing somewhere that adding user to aspnet_users was not necessary in this case.  This does not make sense to me because aspnet_usersInRoles requires UserID and RoleID.  For a valid UserID, I need a user in the aspnet_users table.

Answer (score 0):

After a long frustrating search I finally found a way to get the user (windows authentication).  HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name works for me.  I can't believe I finally stumbled on it.   I hate depending on mysterious frameworks!